# Colin Farrell Got The Last Laugh On “Saturday Night Live” By Shading Their “Offensive” Sketch About Irish People At The Oscars

Tags: word-meaning

What does "shading" mean in the following paragraph? Does it mean to obscure or darken? Thank you!

"[Colin Farrell Got The Last Laugh On “Saturday Night Live” By Shading Their “Offensive” Sketch About Irish People At The Oscars](https://www.buzzfeednews.com/amphtml/ellendurney/colin-farrell-shaded-saturday-night-live-sketch-at-oscars)"

Comment: It's a slang term, so you might have to use a slang dictionary. Where did you look?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is slang, from the term "throw shade", meaning to subtly insult. See [Shade](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/shade#Verb).

Comment: I see several sources referring to this sense of "shade" (and even "throw shade") as slang. I don't know why it should be described as such. I think it's a perfectly common or garden figurative use of the verb.

Comment: I wouldn't have known what it meant.

Comment: Is this a US term? It's not clear from the link & means nothing to me as a Brit.

Comment: @DoneWithThis It has a long history in gay culture and especially drag culture (and even more so in urban, Black drag culture) in both the US and the UK. _RuPaul's Drag Race_ even features a "Shade Button" that the hosts can push when one drag queen makes a particularly cutting remark to another one. It has been increasingly common in mainstream culture largely because of the popularity of shows like _Drag Race_.

Comment: Native speaker, USA. I've never before seen this used as a verb. I have rarely encountered it as a noun as in casting shade. The Merriam-Webster dictionary lists the noun as slang and does not acknowledge this use as a verb. To conclude, I believe this answer is correct to call it slang.

Comment: I'm a bit fascinated by the academic obsession of classifying words as "slang".  When does it stop being slang?  If you dig back far enough, I bet that most modern English words started out as slang in some way or another.  Look at how many words Shakespeare simply made up in his writing that are considered "real" words today.

Comment: @CanadianYankee far more would know of it from rap and hip hop, not drag.  Slim shady, 8 mile etc.

Comment: @CitizenRon: "[Fascinated](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fascinated)"? "[Obsession](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/obsession)"? I don't think these words mean what you think they do . . .

Comment: Thank you so very much for your answer!

Comment: As someone whose partner is massively into RuPaul's Drag Race and drag culture in general, I have not yet heard "shade" as a verb. Only "throw shade", "shady" and variations on these.

Comment: @ruakh:  Nope.  I checked and they're exactly what I meant from my point of view (personal, and US English).  Words are words.  IMO just because some words are new and unknown to many people doesn't mean they are of any less value and thus should be denigrated as inferior words simply to make academics feel superior.  There are serious logical or linguistic failures in the first three definitions of "slang" that I found that either makes almost all modern US English "slang" terms not slang or makes almost every US English word slang.

Comment: @CitizenRon, yes, but learners need to be aware of the different registers of speech.  This is an aspect of language that native speakers don't give much thought to. We are mostly unconsciously aware of these distinctions. Learners are (often) not aware, and it the labels "slang", "formal", "polite" etc help you to learn in which contexts a word can be used.